# How to to allow an element's size (for example, a HBox) grow (overflow) outside the stage it belongs to

Tags: java, javafx, stage

Is it possible to allow an element's size (for example, a HBox) grow (overflow) outside the stage it belongs to, while still being visible, and if so, how can I go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the pane in a group, which is not resizable by the scene. In the following example, if you comment out the current `root.setCenter(...)` and uncomment the one that just adds the hbox, the `HBox` will be constrained to the size of the scene (so the labels will be squeezed smaller and smaller as you add more of them).

When wrapped in a `Group`, the hbox will grow indefinitely.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GrowingHBoxTest extends Application {

    int count = 0 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        Button button = new Button("New label");
        button.setOnAction(e -> hbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label "+(++count))));

        hbox.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(button);

        // will not grow outside of scene bounds:
        root.setCenter(hbox);

        // will grow outside of scene bounds:
//      root.setCenter(new Group(hbox));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```